# Double rotation in SLD style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style

I am facing a problem with Rotation in SLD styling in Geoserver. I have a symbol that consists of two triangles. One of them rotated 180 degrees so that they point towards each other.

So far so good - that works fine for me

But I would also like the total symbol (i.e. the two triangles together) to be rotated based on an attribute value called "Symbolretning"

Whatever I do I cannot get this "dobbeltrotation" to work.

Do any of you a way to solve this? I think the main issue of my problem is where in the SLD code I put the second rotation statement.

Here is my code so far - without the attribute based rotation:

[image]

Comment: please don't post pictures of text - just put the text in the question so we can cut and paste it into our systems to test.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this sort of double rotation in SLD, but you can use maths in the rotation of each symbol to add the value you need. But then you will run into issues with each symbol rotating about their own centres.

So you need to create a single symbol with the two triangles in it (either use [SVG](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#external-graphics) or the [WKT markers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#custom-wkt-shapes)) and then use the rotation attribute directly on that symbol.